# How can I make communication between two fragments in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-framelayout

I'm a new starter of Android. I'm developing my app only by google searching. I learned much things but I couldn't get an answer to this problem.
To use BottomNavigationView, I created two fragment java files and two UI xml files and wrote codes. Until this was good.

```
private FragmentInside Fragment_Inside = new FragmentInside();
private FragmentOutside Fragment_Outside = new FragmentOutside();
...
transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, Fragment_Inside).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Bottomnavview works like this. So no fragments in mainxml, no ID, no tag. I can't use findfragmentbyid.
What I want to do is, if I touch togglebutton2 in fragmentB when togglebutton1 in fragmentA is checked, to make togglebutton1 unchecked. To do this I should be able to get to fragment's resources. but I learned if fragment was made like 'new FragmentA();' I can't. 
I applied many solutions in my way with google searching, but always button wasn't unchecked.
I want to learn how to use bottomView and control fragments' view both.
It's the first time I wrote a question. Thank you. And please help me.

Comment: You can use interface to achieve it

Comment: you can use a shared viewModel for this